# Show that the Cantor set is totally disconnected

Tags: real-analysis, connectedness, cantor-set

So I'm trying to prove that the Cantor set $C$ is totally disconnected - that is, for any two points $x, y \in C$ there is a $z \notin C$ where either $x < z < y$ or $y < z < x$. I'd like to check if my argument proves this proposition.

First I assume without loss of generality that $x < y$.

Next, we fix $k \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}$. If $|x - y| > 1/3^k$ we can easily argue that $x$ and $y$ are in two different subintervals of $C_k$ and choosing $z \notin C$ is straightforward.

If $|x - y| \leq 1/3^k$, then the two points are in the same subinterval of $C_k$. But since $x \neq y$, then we can choose a $1 \geq \delta > 0$ such that $|x - y| = \delta$. Now all we have to do is choose $n > 0$ such that $|x - y| = \delta > 1/3^{k + n}$. With some rearrangement we have $n > - k - \log_3(\delta)$ which means if we choose $n = -k + \lceil - \log_3(|x - y|)\rceil + 1$, then the set $C_{k + n} = C_{\lceil - \log_3(|x - y|)\rceil + 1}$ will result in $x$ and $y$ not being in the same subinterval. So there would exist a $z \notin C$ between $x$ and $y$.

How does my proof look?

Comment: a minimal choice of $k$ exists, i.e., there exists a natural $k\geq 0$ such that $|x-y|>1/3^k$ so why not just use that? then you're in the first case and you're done

Comment: @CSquared I'm going to sound annoying here, but why can I just say that there's a minimal choice of $k$?

Comment: The sequence $x_k=3^{-k}$ converges to $0$, so there is a natural $K\geq 0$ such that $3^{-k}<|x-y|$ for all $k\geq K$.  Choose the smallest such $K$ (which exists since they form a non-empty subset of naturals), or any such $K$ really.

Comment: I see. If I could mark that comment as the answer I would. Thanks!

Comment: Was there anywhere you used $x < y$?

Comment: @BrianMoehring Seems like I didn't. I suppose I could get rid of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A minimal choice of $k$ exists because the sequence $3^{-k}$ converges to $0$, i.e., there is an integer $K$ such that for all $k\geq K$, we have $3^{-k}<|x-y|$. By choosing any such $k\geq K$, we can argue that $x$ and $y$ are in different sub-intervals without cases.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is OK. It can be simplified as follows.

Suppose $y>x.\,$ Let $k\in \Bbb{N}\,$ be that $\,1/3^k<y-x<1/3^{k-1}.\,$ Then there is an interval $I=\left(l/3^{k+1}, (l+1)/3^{k+1}\right)\:(0\leqslant l<3^{k+1}-1)\:$ such that $I\subset(x,y)\,$ but $\,I\cap C=\varnothing.\,$ By choosing a $\,z\in I,\,$ we have $\,z\in (x,y)$ and $\,z\notin C$.

Comment: What does $\left(1/3^{k+1}, 2/3^{k+1}\right)\subset|x-y|$ mean? And what if $1/3^k=|x-y|$ fo some $k$?

Comment: $|x-y|$ is a real number.

Comment: Could you please explain why $\left(1/3^{k+1}, 2/3^{k+1}\right)\subset(x,y)$ and why $\left(1/3^{k+1}, 2/3^{k+1}\right)\cap C = \emptyset$?